# download a pdf using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download a pdf from the internet.  I have a battery of links needed to pull the pdf from the internet.
I have this block of code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
url = 'http://webapps.rrc.texas.gov/CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplG1FormPdf&packetSummaryId=2928'
opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
assert opts.headless  # Operating in headless mode
browser_detail = Firefox(options=opts)
browser_detail.get(url)
print(browser_detail.page_source)


with open('temp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as fd:
    fd.write(browser_detail.page_source)

browser_detail.close()
```

I also have tried requests.  Same response:

```
import requests

url = 'http://webapps.rrc.texas.gov/CMPL/viewPdfReportFormAction.do?method=cmplG1FormPdf&packetSummaryId=2928'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open('temp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(2000):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

the problem is if I put the url into a browser, the pdf comes up, but when I put it to this code, the page_source is html.  This makes me think that there's a forwarding or server-side processing involved.

How do I get the PDF down?
Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you're using `selenium` versus, say, `requests` if all you're doing is pulling down PDFs?

Comment: Hi Carlos.  Great question.  Yes.  Have tried requests.  Got the same response.  I updated the question.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to pull down the PDF file using `requests`.

The page is looking for a proper `User-Agent` so I set it to Chrome MacOS.

```
h = {"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36" }

r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=h)
```

And it worked.

```
tmp/project/1> file metadata.pdf
metadata.pdf: PDF document, version 1.4
```

Comment: How did you know it needed a User-Agent?

Comment: So, the `viewPdfReportFormAction.do` tells me it's an Apache Struts application and from past experience, I had a hunch they'd be particular about User-Agents.

Answer (score -3):

```
with open('temp/metadata.pdf', 'wb') as fd:
    fd.write(r.content)
```